# SQL Server Merge XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-merge

Пытаюсь создать процедуру вставки/обновления данных в таблице Region базы данных NORTHWND

```
USE NORTHWND;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_Update_Region
(@Request xml)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @doc nvarchar(1000);
    DECLARE @xmlDoc integer;
    EXEC sp_XML_preparedocument @xmlDoc OUTPUT, @doc;
    MERGE INTO Region as r
        USING 
        (
            SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@xmlDoc, 'Regions/Region', 0) 
            WITH 
            (
                RegionID int,
                RegionDescription nchar(50)
            )
        ) as temp (RegionID, RegionDescription)
        ON (r.RegionID = temp.RegionID)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET r.RegionDescription = temp.RegionDescription   
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (r.RegionDescription)
        VALUES (temp.RegionDescription);
    EXEC sp_XML_removedocument @xmlDoc;
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
END
```

Ругается на строку 22 (ON (r.RegionID = temp.RegionID)) с сообщением "Список вставляемых столбцов, используемый в инструкции MERGE, не может содержать составные идентификаторы. Используйте однокомпонентные идентификаторы."
Как решить?
Подозреваю, что в temp нужно указать первичный ключ, но не знаю как. Пробовал вынести в отдельную переменную таблицу с выборкой из XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось заменой строки 24 на следующую

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (RegionDescription)
```

Убрал алиас из списка вставляемых значений.